# Using Scheme Markup for Company Reviews

Tags: seo, microdata, local-seo, user-reviews

this is my first post in here, i was hoping someone would be able to help me out a little. I'm trying to get my head around using Schema markup for a company website to show their reviews of the company itself.

I am having trouble getting to grips with where exactly on the site i need to add the info and markup, so, do i need to create a specific page on the site for company reviews? And do i list this as a corporation/organisation and then have review markup inside of there? I am just curious as how to the review ratings can be display on the homepage URL in search results if i need to do this on a seperate URL.

Any guidence or help with this would be massively appreciated - I've been reading through the Schema site and understand the technical side of what to do, i am just a little unsure of where i need to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help or if anyone has any useful links/resources that they could recommend for further reading

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you **markup the visible content that you already have**.

("Ideally" because it’s also possible to add hidden Schema.org data which could be added to any/each page, but search engines typically prefer visible content.)

[For HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669), this means that you’d have to use **Microdata and/or RDFa** (see my answer [about their differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)).